# How to Call to HashPassword and to store User password to database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, password-hash

I'm setting up a HashPassword function using SHA1CryptoServiceProvider(). My requirement includes two methods: generate the salt and initializer which I need help with.

Salt is used with the IV which is used to salt the password before it is hashed, and the password to validate.  The initializer takes the string made by the salt generator it mixes the password and salt into one string and add's any extra characters to the end then hash the blended password and returns the value.

Essentially, I need to compare if the value sent from the view differs from the original and if it does then i need to regenerate the hash and initializer on a create(new record).

This controller action calls the HashPassword functions in the USERController.Helper file.

```
    public ActionResult HashPassword(USERSModel UsersModel)
    {
        USERDto dto = new USERDto();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string hashedPassword = UsersModel.PASSWORD;
            UsersModel.PASSWORD = hashedPassword;
            dto.Updated.Add(hashedPassword);
            dto.Updated.Add("NAME");
            dto.Updated.Add("ID");
            dto.Updated.Add("PASSWORD");
            UsersModel.Updated.SaveChanges();

            ViewBag.Message = "User was added successfully!";
            UsersModel = new USERSModel();

        }
        else
            ViewBag.message = "Error in adding User!";


        return View("USERSSettingsPartial", UsersModel);
    }

 /// <summary>
    /// Called to hash a user password to be stored in the DB.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="password">The password to validate.</param>
    /// <param name="salt">The IV used to salt the password before it is hashed.</param>
    /// <param name="errorDesc">Returns an error description if an error occurs.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns the hashed password as a HEX string on success, otherwise returns null.</returns>

        private string HashPassword(string password, byte[] salt, ref string errorDesc)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] newPassword = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password.ToUpper());
                if (salt != null && salt.Length > 0)
                {
                    int count = (salt.Length < newPassword.Length) ? salt.Length : newPassword.Length;
                    byte[] temp = new byte[salt.Length + newPassword.Length];
                    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
                    {
                        temp[index * 2] = newPassword[index];
                        temp[index * 2 + 1] = salt[index];
                    }
                    if (count == salt.Length && count < newPassword.Length)
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(newPassword, count, temp, count * 2, newPassword.Length - count);
                    else if (count == newPassword.Length && count < salt.Length)
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, count, temp, count * 2, salt.Length - count);

                    newPassword = temp;
                }
                using (var hash = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
                {
                    hash.ComputeHash(newPassword);
                    return this.GetHexStringFromBytes(hash.Hash);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                errorDesc = Ex.Message;
                if (Ex.InnerException != null) errorDesc = string.Format("{0}\r\n{1}", errorDesc, Ex.InnerException.Message);
            }
            return null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// called to convert byte data into hexidecimal string were each byte is represented as two hexidecimal characters.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="data">Byte data to convert.</param>
        /// <returns>A hexidecimal string version of the data.</returns>
        private string GetHexStringFromBytes(byte[] data)
        {
            if (data == null || data.Length == 0) return string.Empty;

            StringBuilder sbHex = new StringBuilder();
            for (int index = 0; index < data.Length; index++) sbHex.AppendFormat(null, "{0:X2}", data[index]);

            return sbHex.ToString();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// called to convert hexadecimal string into byte data were two hexadecimal characters are converted into a byte.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hexString">A hexidecimal string to convert</param>
        /// <returns>The converted byte data.</returns>
        private byte[] GetBytesFromHexString(string hexString)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hexString)) return null;

            byte[] data = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
            for (int index = 0; index < data.Length; index++)
            {
                data[index] = byte.Parse(hexString.Substring(index * 2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
            }
            return data;
        }
```

This is my first go around with a project like this, therefore I don't have any output.  Just need examples to understand better.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using ASP.NET Identity which is far more secure and error-prone that your code?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i'm having to replicate a vb6 desktop application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically needed to have a Controller in a Service where this class will create the salt and be called from a Controller Helper class.  What I did was set the Initializer on the server side where in turn added code to the USERS service controller create IHttpActionResult which sets the salt and password. You never want to store passwords in your database, always want to hash them.
 I created a request in the service controller of the USERS passing in DTO which is used to create a new record, returning an object containing the query results if any, otherwise returns not found or internal server error message.  Within this method Salt is being called:

```
public IHttpActionResult Create([FromBody]USERDto dto)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        try
        {
            byte[] saltValue;
            string error = string.Empty;

            saltValue = GenerateSalt();
            dto.INITIALIZER = GetHexStringFromBytes(saltValue);
            dto.PASSWORD = HashPassword(dto.PASSWORD, saltValue, ref error);

            USERDto created = USERSProcessor.Create(dto);
            if (created == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(created);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogUtility.LogError(ex);
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Then (to not clutter controller) I created a controller helper class & added this code to implement the hashing salt methods, where the USERSController calls to the hash password to be stored in the database, as well as the dto.INITIALIZER is called to convert byte data into hexadecimal string where each byte is represented as two hexadecimal characters:

```
partial class USERSController
{    
    /// <summary>
    /// Called to generate salt byte array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The generated salt byte array.</returns>
    public static byte[] GenerateSalt()
    {
        byte[] iv;
        using (var alg = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            alg.BlockSize = 128; //block size is 8bytes, which is the the size of the IV generated.
            alg.KeySize = 256; //key size is 32bytes
            alg.GenerateIV();
            iv = alg.IV;
        }

        return iv;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Called to hash a user password to be stored in DB.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="password">The password to validate.</param>
    /// <param name="salt">The IV used to salt the password before it is hashed.</param>
    /// <param name="errorDesc">Returns an error description if an error occurs.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns the hashed password as a HEX string on success, otherwise returns null.</returns>
    private static string HashPassword(string password, byte[] salt, ref string errorDesc)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] newPassword = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password.ToUpper());
            if (salt != null && salt.Length > 0)
            {
                int count = (salt.Length < newPassword.Length) ? salt.Length : newPassword.Length;
                byte[] temp = new byte[salt.Length + newPassword.Length];
                for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
                {
                    temp[index * 2] = newPassword[index];
                    temp[index * 2 + 1] = salt[index];
                }
                if (count == salt.Length && count < newPassword.Length)
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(newPassword, count, temp, count * 2, newPassword.Length - count);
                else if (count == newPassword.Length && count < salt.Length)
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, count, temp, count * 2, salt.Length - count);

                newPassword = temp;
            }
            using (var hash = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                hash.ComputeHash(newPassword);
                return GetHexStringFromBytes(hash.Hash);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            errorDesc = Ex.Message;
            if (Ex.InnerException != null) errorDesc = string.Format("{0}\r\n{1}", errorDesc, Ex.InnerException.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// called to convert byte data into hexidecimal string were each byte is represented as two hexidecimal characters.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data">Byte data to convert.</param>
    /// <returns>A hexidecimal string version of the data.</returns>
    private static string GetHexStringFromBytes(byte[] data)
    {
        if (data == null || data.Length == 0) return string.Empty;

        StringBuilder sbHex = new StringBuilder();
        for (int index = 0; index < data.Length; index++) sbHex.AppendFormat(null, "{0:X2}", data[index]);

        return sbHex.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// called to convert hexidecimal string into byte data were two hexidecimal characters are converted into a byte.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hexString">A hexidecimal string to convert</param>
    /// <returns>The converted byte data.</returns>
    private static byte[] GetBytesFromHexString(string hexString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hexString)) return null;

        byte[] data = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
        for (int index = 0; index < data.Length; index++)
        {
            data[index] = byte.Parse(hexString.Substring(index * 2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
        }
        return data;
    }       

}
```